# Azure custom application SSO using SAML and azure active directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I’m kind of new to azure active directory. What I'm trying to achieve is:
I have a .net core application (backend api) which will be called using an angular application.
My requirement is to authenticate and enable single sign on using azure active directory.

With some time spent, I came to know that there are 2 ways to do this,

1. Using OpenID Connect
2. Using SAML

I would like to do using SAML. I tried implementing SAML SSO as follows:

1. I registered one application under Active directory which redirects
   to my angular application. I also read that, any application we are
   registering in App registrations will use OpenID by default and
   there is no UI available to make it as SAML but we can do the same
   using manifest.
2. We can register application using Enterprise applications to enable
   SAML

My question is,

1. Is there a way we can authenticate and enable SSO in my application
   registered using App registrations?
2. What options I should choose to enable SAML SSO while registering
   enterprise application? If I select my registered application in
   enterprise application it gives me the following:

> The single sign-on configuration is not available for this application in the Enterprise applications experience. localhost was created using the App registrations experience.

> Please go to localhost in the App registrations experience to edit properties such as reply URLs, identifiers, claims, among others. Your account should have the required permissions (Global Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the app object).

3. What will be the code changes in my angular and .net core
   application?

Any reference would be very helpful.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from App Registrations but you can do it from the [Enterprise Application experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso). To set up SAML SSO you need to go to the application > Manage > Single Sign-On > Select SAML. The [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso) goes through all of the steps for setting up SAML SSO from Enterprise Applications.

[image]

For Basic SAML configuration values, see [Configure SAML Single Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on).

You can use the [SAML toolkit](http://%20https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/saas-apps/saml-toolkit-tutorial.md) and accompanying samples to test the SAML single sign-on integration with Azure AD

Comment: If the app was first registered using app registration, then the above will not work as you will get the nice error message posted by Arun.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marilee's, her answer has provided some related documents on how to create an enterprise app and how to enable SSO with the app.

What I wanna add is that I think you need to figure out which app you are willing to connect together with SSO, I mean that you just said 'an angular application', so there's only one app, how does it relate to SSO ? And if you just need to sign in both frontend app and backend app, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) may help.

Wish you could solve it soon, and if you met more questions, pls add details.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. To be precise, I have an angular front end application (let's assume it is running at url https://demoanugualapp.com). when i visit that url it should not ask login detail if an user is logged into microsoft account. Just like when i logged into google it won't ask login detail for gmail,youtube etc.,

Comment: I did an experiment locally, I signed out my youtube in my chrome which has signed in with google account. And refreshed the website and it still needed to sign in, when I clicked the button and redirected to the login page, it provided a choice to use google account to sign in. So I think what you need is that your website can sign in with microsoft account and when you have signed in, you don't need to sign in again in the browser for a long time, right?

Comment: Like single sign on, there is one more option available for single sign off. When you log out from youtube it would've logged out from google as well. That is the reason it again asks for login. What i'm trying to achieve is, i'll open my angular hosted url in browser, at that point in time if some user is logged into microsoft account then it should not ask for login again. If no one logged into microsoft account on the browser then it can ask for login.

Comment: I'm sorry that I think your request is not achievable. From my point of view, if you have signed in ms account such as azure portal, then in the same browser, you opened a new tab and visit your angular app(demoangularapp.com), then how can your website get the information that there is a ms account has signed in. I think it's illegal except that your website is embedded into azure portal. And on the other hand, if your website has signed in, then you sign out azure portal and refresh portal.azure.com, can it login automatically?  If you solve it finally, hope you can share your solution here.